# Deciding whether a collection of sets is a partition

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, set-partition

Which of the following collections of sets is a partition of [0,∞)?

A. $S_i$ = (i-1,i) for i =1, 2, 3, …

B. $S_i$ = (i-1,i] for i =1, 2, 3, …

C. $S_1$ = (0,1], $S_i$ = [i-1,i] for i = 2, 3, 4, …

D. $S_1$ = (0,π], $S_2$ = (π,350π), $S_2$ = [350π,∞)

E. All of these

I'm having trouble answering this, I know what a partition is, however I'm having trouble with the notation of this problem...
Is the the set [0,∞)= {0,1,2,3,4,5....}

For example, choice (A. $S_i$ = (i-1,i) for i =1, 2, 3, …) the sets would be

$S_1$ = (0,1), $S_2$ = (1,2), $S_3$ = (2,3)....

So are these sets disjoint, and additionally is the union of them equal to [0,∞)?

Thanks

Comment: $[0,\infty )$ is the set of non-negative real numbers. The sets of $A$ are disjoint but they don't cover $[0,\infty )$ (natural numbers are not covered).

Comment: @Augustin If I were to do $S_1$ ∪ $S_2$ for A. it would be (0,1) ∪ (1,2), what is the result of this union?

Comment: It is $(0,2)\setminus\{1\}$.

Comment: @Augustin It's {1} since 1 lies in the interval (0,2), is this the correct way of thinking?

Comment: None of them includes $0$ so all fail to be a cover of $[0,\infty)$. So they cannot be a partition of $[0,\infty)$.

Comment: $(0,1)$ is the set of all $x$ such that $0<x<1$ and $(1,2)$ the set of all $x$ such that $1<x<2$. So the union of these two intervals is the set of $x$ such that $0<x<2$ and $x\neq 1$.